# Entropy of unattended music streaming and other useless processes

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I just realized that on my work pc, I had an internet music streaming service turned on for the last week, but muted (=useless). I was wondering how much entropy in excess was generated by transferring the data over the cables and how it compares with other similarly useless processes.

Comment: As a side note: your computer simply being switched on and pumping out heat will have increased the entropy of the universe by *orders of magnitude* more than that associated with the streaming of music.

Comment: @lemon: exactly. That makes the "computer on" process a good candidate for comparison.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question, do you mean the entropy generated due to heat transferred  from the source to your computer (related to thermodynamic entropy) or the amount of information entropy in the encoded message (related to shannon's entropy). I am not an expert but I am sure these two will result in different answers.